# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

Tags: swift, keyboard

Hey so I keep getting this every time i try running the code to close the keyboard every other part works until i add these lines of code.
If anyone can help that would be great thank you!

Code starts here

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) 

{

        self.view.endEditing(true)

        //closes keyboard
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true

    }

}
```

Comment: Check your `textField` Outlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) 
{

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.text != nil
    {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    you can also try
    if textField != nil
    {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true

 }
}
```

Try this

Comment: That is what i originally had but now it says "Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is 'UITextField'. Now it  fails to build and to fix it it wants to remove the question mark.

Comment: I actually just rewrote all the code again for the app and the error went away even though i had the same exact code do you possible know why the error stayed even after i fixed it? and thank you for your time and effort!